# What is the extension of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ with $1/p$ where $p$ is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

I am solving a problem from a ring theory problem set: describe the ring $\mathbb{Z}[u]$ when $u$ is $\frac{1}{p}$, where $p$ is prime. $\mathbb{Z}[u]$ is the image in $\mathbb{C}$ of the unique ring homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\phi(x)=u$, i.e. it is the ring of polynomials in $u$ with integer coefficients. It seems obvious that $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ consists exactly of all rationals that have finite base $p$ expansion (is this the word?) fraction. However, is there something more to this problem? Why is it stressed that $p$ is prime? Is there a nicer way to describe the resulting set?

Comment: "finite $p$-simal fractions" is not standard terminology so you must define it.

Comment: Numbers that have a finite number of non-zero digits in base p

Comment: It always seemed to me that if $p$ is prime, then
$$
\mathbb{Z}[1/p]=\left\{\frac{n}{p^k}\mid n,k\in\mathbb{Z},\ k\geq0\right\}.
$$
Isn't that right?

Comment: Yes, and these are exactly the rational numbers that have finite number of digits in base $p$. Why do we need $p$ to be prime?

Also, no, not quite correct, you need to consider linear combinations of terms of this form.

Comment: While "decimal" refers to powers of 10, the way to describe this with $p$ in place of 10 is "base $p$ expansion".  Or say $n/p^k$ has "$p$-power denominator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me then answer all of your questions in more detail.

1. The set of rational numbers of the form
   $$
   \mathbb{Z}[1/p]=\left\{\frac{n}{p^k}\mid n,k\in\mathbb{Z},\ k\geq0\right\}
   $$
   for prime $p$ is a ring.
   Indeed, $1/p\in\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ and
   $$
   \frac{n}{p^k}+\frac{m}{p^l}=\frac{p^ln+p^km}{p^{k+l}},\
   \frac{n}{p^k}\cdot\frac{m}{p^l}=\frac{mn}{p^{k+l}}.
   $$
2. If $m$ is a composite number, then the ring $\mathbb{Z}[1/m]$
   is given by the same formula
   $$
   \mathbb{Z}[1/m]=\left\{\frac{n}{m^k}\mid n,k\in\mathbb{Z},\ k\geq0\right\}.
   $$
   One thing we should notice is that when $m$ is prime we can put all such fractions in reduced form with denominator being a power of $m$, but in the case of composite $m$ these fractions might not have a reduced form with denominator being a power of $m$.
   To fix this defect we can do the following.
   If, for example, $m=6$, then the following is true:
   $$
   \mathbb{Z}[1/6]=\left\{\frac{n}{2^k3^l}\mid n,k,l\in\mathbb{Z},\ k,l\geq0\right\}.
   $$
   We can put such fractions in reduced form when written this way.
   It is clear that a similar formula is valid for all composite numbers $m$.

Have I answered your questions?

Comment: Я исправил несколко грамматических ошибок.

Comment: Yes, this explains why it is stressed that the number is prime. I have overlooked the fact that in the case of prime numbers you can express every linear combination in the resulting ring as a monomial, thank you

Comment: @KCd, спасибо большое.

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku that property ("you can express every linear combination in the resulting ring as a monomial") is true in $\mathbf Z[1/m]$ even when $m$ is composite: it is the set of all $n/m^k$ with $n \in \mathbf Z$ and $k \geq 0$.